define foreign keys converting an ER Diagram into tables in SQL
I am converting an ER Diagram I did into tables in SQL.
How do I define my foreign keys?
I tried two ways but the one where I am referencing does not run and the other doesn't  work.
    create table Employee (
        employeeID int not null ,
        employeeName varChar(20) not null ,
        employeeAddress varChar(40) not null ,
        employeeNumber int not null ,
        hireDate date not null ,
        employeePosition VarChar(30) not null ,
        employeeStatus VarChar(15) not null , 
        PRIMARY KEY (employeeID)
    );
    
    create table Memberships (
        membershipID varChar(20) not null ,
        joiningFee float not null ,
        discount float not null ,
        PRIMARY KEY (membershipID)
    );
    
    create table Member (
        memberID int not null ,
        memberName varChar(20) not null , 
        memberAdress varChar(40) not null ,
        memberPhone int not null ,
        memberGender varChar(20) ,
        birthDate date not null ,
        dateJoined date not null ,
        membershipID int not null ,
        PRIMARY KEY (memberID) ,
        KEY idx_fk_membershipID (membershipID) 
    );
    
    create table PurchaseTransaction (
        transactionNumber int not null ,
        transactionDate date not null ,
        itemPurchased varChar(40) ,
        quantity int not null ,
        pricePerUnit float not null ,
        overallTotal float not null ,
        PRIMARY KEY (transactionNumber) ,
        FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member (memberID) ,
        FOREIGN KEY (employeeID) REFERENCES Employee (employeeID)
    );
    
    create table StoreItem (
        itemID int not null ,
        itemDescription varChar(40) not null ,
        standardPrice float not null ,
        quantity int not null ,
        reorderPoint varChar(40) ,
        PRIMARY KEY (itemID) ,
        FOREIGN KEY (vendorID) REFERENCES Vendor (vendorID)
    );
    
    create table SupplyOrder (
        orderNumber int not null ,
        datePlaced date not null ,
        dateReceived date ,
        itemOrdered varChar(40) not null ,
        quantityOrdered int not null ,
        quantityReceived int ,
        costCharged float not null ,
        totalCost float not null ,
        PRIMARY KEY (orderNumber) ,
        FOREIGN KEY (employeeID) REFERENCES Employee (employeeID)
    );
    
    create table Vendor  (
        vendorID int not null ,
        companyName varChar(40) not null ,
        companyAddress varchar(40) not null ,
        companyNumber int not null ,
        faxNumber int ,
        PRIMARY KEY (vendorID)
    );
    
    create table Class (
        referenceNumberID int not null ,
        employeeID int ,
        startDate date not null , 
        daysHeld varChar(30) not null ,
        timePeriod varChar(30) not null ,
        PRIMARY KEY (referenceNumber_ID) ,
        FOREIGN KEY (employee_ID) REFERENCES Employee(employee_ID) , 
        FOREIGN KEY (roomNumber) REFERENCES Room(roomNumber)
    );
    
    create table FitnessCourse (
        courseNumberID int not null ,
        courseName varChar(30) not null ,
        courseDescription varChar(50) ,
        courseCategory varChar(30) not null ,
        courseDuration time not null ,
        courseFee int not null ,
        PRIMARY KEY (courseNumberID)
    );
    
    create table Room (
        roomNumber int not null ,
        classCapacity int not null ,
        PRIMARY KEY (roomNumberID) ,
        FOREIGN KEY (exerciseEquipment) REFERENCES EquipmentType(equipmentDecription)
    );
    
    create table EquipmentType (
        identificationNumber int not null ,
        equipmentDescription varChar(40) not null ,
        manufacturerModelNumber int not null , 
        maintenenceInterval varChar(40) ,
        PRIMARY KEY (identifcationNumber)
    );
    
    create table ExerciseEquipment (
        serialNumber int not null ,
        purchaseDate date not null ,
        lastMaintenance date ,
        PRIMARY KEY (serialNumnber)
    );
    
    create table Manufacturer  (
        manufacturerID int not null ,
        companyName varChar(40) ,
        companyAddress varChar(40) ,
        companyPhone int not null ,
        faxNumber int ,
        PRIMARY KEY (manufacturerID)
    );
    
    create table WorkOrder (
        workOrderID int not null ,
        orderDate date not null ,
        serialNumber int not null ,
        amountCharged float not null ,
        PRIMARY KEY (workorderID) ,
        FOREIGN KEY (manufacturerID) REFERENCES Manufacturer(manufactuerID)
    );


What does make transfer the data between tables actually mean? A foreign key doesn't copy/transfer data, it just verifies consistency.

No idea what you want to do or how we should help. You just showed some create table commands and talk something about a "method" and "transfer data" where no one knows what you talk about. Please ask your question in a clear way that everyone understands.

KEY idx_fk_membershipID creates an index not a foreign key and (all?) the foreign keys you have defined are incorrect for example in the table PurchaseTransaction FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member (memberID) , memberid has to exist in the table PurchaseTransaction as well as the member table and their attributes have to be the same. You should review foreign keys here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html and elsewhere on the net.

@JonasMetzler Hi, so sorry I totally get what you're saying. It was really late and I was delirious and desperate. I just meant that I am just starting SQL and I'm not sure how to correctly define foreign keys and when I did find a method that worked, it was not correctly reading the data that I added to the tables. I.e. the foreign key in Member for membership ID was not outputting anything. I hope this is clearer? I apologize for my weird and confusing wording

@P.Salmon Hi, thank you! I did a google search, chatgpt ask, and looked at a previous lengthy code my professor gave me and tried to work from there and obviously still could not figure out the correct way to define foreign keys. I wasn't aware that was just an index, I was just going based off a code from my professor. Thank you! I appreciate the feedback.

The easiest way to establish the foreign key constraints is (probably): just write REFERENCES inline ie in the same line as the column definition when you code your CREATE TABLE statements eg
create table oneside (
  id int primary key
) ;

-- This still does not work in MySQL version 8 ...
create table manyside (
  id int primary key
, oneside_id int references oneside( id )
) ;

However, the above solution does not work in MySQL, although it will not cause any errors (see Bill Karwin's comment).  Make sure that you write the column definition first, and then add the foreign key eg
create table manyside (
  id int primary key
, oneside_id int 
, foreign key( oneside_id ) references oneside( id ) 
) ;

Notice the the column name oneside_id is mentioned twice in the above example.
dbfiddle
You are referencing the correct columns eg in CREATE TABLE PurchaseTransactions, but the foreign key column itself does not exist (as it were) ie PurchaseTransactions in your example does not have the memberID column or the employeeID column.  Thus, there are difficulties with these two foreign keys.
dbfiddle

MySQL does not implement inline foreign key syntax. It parses the syntax, but does not create a foreign key constraint. It does not return an error or warning in this case. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17943
